# Avoid performance issues when adding onscroll manipulations

Tags: javascript, dom

I am about to add a bunch of scroll effects on a website, but previous times I have experienced here some performance issues, as there are many fading or transforming effects inside the `onscroll` event.

To avoid those, I am wondering which is the less harmful way to trigger DOM manipulations depending on user's depth.

Is it better to get once, store and reuse user's depth?:

```
let depth;
window.onscroll = () => {
   depth = window.scrollY
   depth > 200 ? whateverId.classList.add('visible') : whateverId.classList.remove('visible')
   depth > 800 ? whateverId.classList.add('visible') : whateverId.classList.remove('visible')
   // more similar code
}
```

Or better getting it on every instruction?:

```
window.onscroll = () => {
   window.scrollY > 200 ? whateverId.classList.add('visible') : whateverId.classList.remove('visible')
   window.scrollY > 800 ? whateverId.classList.add('visible') : whateverId.classList.remove('visible')
   // more similar code
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a problem that is commonly solved using a "debounce".  The idea is that your event handler only actually fires once if lots of events get fired off in quick succession.  The word comes from the realm of electronics.  Try searching for 'javascript debounce'.

Comment: `MutationObserver` is what you're looking for. Google "mutationobserver scroll event" (Or something similar for a good tutorial)

Comment: Those contributions are so useful for me. Thank you.